# Python time conversion format of 2017-10-15T03:15:04.293

Tags: python, date

I am having trouble converting the date time string `2017-10-15T03:15:04.293` into a Date object in python, simply because I can't figure out the format.

I have the code line: `x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, which accurately gives me the date itself, but lacks the time obviously. When trying to modify the string formatter, I am getting confused by the `T`, and the last decimal `.293` (from the example above).

Can someone help me understand what these values mean in this timestamp, and what the proper `x.strftime('<WHAT GOES HERE ???>')` might be?

Comment: *"what these values mean in this timestamp "* -
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior. See also many duplicates on parsing ISO 8601 datetimes, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/3001761

Comment: I posted my answer as @jonrsharpe updated his comment. My answer will work, but I agree with him that this should really be marked a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers after the `.` are microseconds. You can parse it using the `datetime` module, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2017-10-15T03:15:04.293', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

The format looks like ISO-8601, which is a widely-used standard. But it appears that [the `datetime` module doesn't yet provide a way](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873) to parse this without providing the format-string yourself.